# Exercise 1-6. Verify that the expression getchar() != EOF is 0 or 1

Tags: c, getchar

I was reading the C Answer Book by Clovis L. Tondo and Scott E. Gimpel to see how they coded up the solution for this problem.
Here is how it appears in that book:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main() 
{
  int c;

  while (c = getchar() != EOF) /* <-- This test results in compilation errors */
    printf("%d\n", c);
  printf("%d - at EOF\n", c);
}
```

Compilation errors when the above code is saved into a file called `ex1.6.c` and executed like below:

```
bash-3.2$ clang -Wall ex1.6.c
ex1.6.c:2:1: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
main()
^
ex1.6.c:6:12: warning: using the result of an assignment as a condition without parentheses [-Wparentheses]
  while (c = getchar() != EOF)
         ~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ex1.6.c:6:12: note: place parentheses around the assignment to silence this warning
  while (c = getchar() != EOF)
           ^
         (                   )
ex1.6.c:6:12: note: use '==' to turn this assignment into an equality comparison
  while (c = getchar() != EOF)
           ^
           ==
2 warnings generated.
```

So, looks like the solution in the C Answer Book is wrong. Am I right?

Here is what I tried as a solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
        int c;
        printf( "%d\n",( getchar() != EOF));
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's not good code by modern standards because of the compilation warning, but it is correct.  It should now be written `while (c = (getchar() != EOF)) printf("%d\n", c);` which will print `1` until it encounters EOF.

Comment: There are no compilation errors.

Comment: It's also bad code because it crams the assignment into the `while()` expression.  Cramming the assignment into the conditional expression is so bug-prone it's a banned style in  standards such as MISRA that deal with critical issues such as safety.

Comment: Is it the first one you have tried from this book? Every single program from there will provoke at least one warning on a modern compiler because of the implicit int rule that is used throughout the book.

Answer (score 0):

It's a **warning** and not an error. But the warning is correct because you almost never want that behavior in a boolean context like `if` or `while`. `c = getchar() != EOF` is parsed as `c = (getchar() != EOF)` because [`=` has lower precedence than `!=`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), so `c` will have value 0 or 1 depending on the value `getchar()` returns which is what you expected

Most of the time people want it to return the read character so parentheses must be put around the `=` expression to force the assignment to be done first

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
```

Comment: Based on the title, the intent is not to print the characters returned or to assign them to `c`. The intent is to examine the values taken by `getchar() != EOF`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I already said that in the first paragraph

Comment: No, this answer does not say, or explicitly acknowledge, the intent is to display the values of `getchar() != EOF`. If the first paragraph is intended to say that the message may be ignored because it is only a warning, then it should say that explicitly. In any case, OP asked “So, looks like the solution in the C Answer Book is wrong. Am I right?”, and no answer to that appears in this post.